# Will changing an SSL binding to new certificate in IIS7 affect Application Pools, i.e. cause them to recycle?

Tags: iis-7, ssl, asp.net, application-pools

I want to change SSL bindings to a replacement certificate, but don't want to affect logged in users.

Will doing this cause the Application Pools for the web site to recycle?

Many thanks,

Kenny

Comment: If I remove SSL binding completely and then re-add the same again, my app pool is still running without recycling. But the app pool I have tested runs PHP via FastCGI which may work completely different to the asp.net (hence the comment a not the answer).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, good to know. Still keen to find out if it'll affect Asp.Net apps.

Comment: Well, you can try this (if you can, of course -- maybe this app is not designed to work on non-standard ports etc): 1) duplicate your site in question on another app pool (put it on the same SSL certificate but different port); 2) login as a customer there; 3) replace certificates and see if it the job (if I understand correctly you will be logged out on website if app pool recycles). **If** you need to perform this operation rather urgently it may be quicker compared for someone posting the 100%-assured answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I have just done this in IIS7.5 and it did reset the application pool